# Sort list of objects based on the size of sub-arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of Objects:
[variable , variable , variable , ...]
which each have an array called domain.
As example: variable.domain = ["aa" , "bbb" , "c" , "dddd"].
I need this variable list sorted by the size of the domain arrays. 
How can i sort this list using .sort() or .sorted() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a key function

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: len(x.domain))
```

or

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.domain))
```